# In app purchase: Необходимо войти в аккаунт Google

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play, in-app-purchases

Пользуюсь [этой либой для in-app purchasing](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3)
Но есть ошибка, пишет "Необходимо войти в аккаунт Google". Приложения ещё нет в Play Market'e. И как проверить работает ли до релиза?

Comment: Мало информации для получения ответа. Покажите код. А проверить можно выложив приложение в бета версию.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб нууу. android.test.purchase сработало, вроде. 
А Бету. ну это уже заказчику надо сказать) Ладно, посмотрю что в Бетте будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет ! Я думаю стоит сначала создать приложение в google play но при этом не выкладывать апк. После создания ты можешь скопировать лицензионный ключ приложения из google play который закреплен за этим приложением, и использовать его в cамом приложении. По ключу уже должно пускать. Еще рекомендую после указанного выше выкладывать альфа версию и указать себя в перечне тестеров. Тогда вроде бы будет фейковая покупка.